# printing out System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FIrstproject] when trying to print out list c#

Tags: c#

Trying to print out a list:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        
          List<Test> Test = GetTest();

          Console.WriteLine(Newlist);

}
 public static List<Test> GetTest()
        {
            List<Test> Test = new List<Test>
           {
                new Test{ ID = 1, Points = 100 }
           };
        return Test;
        }
```

When i try to print it out it wont work. I also can mess with the data like doing Test.ID I can get that but I can't print out the list. how do i print out the list object?

C#

Comment: C and C# are two radically different languages — it is rarely correct to use both tags.

Comment: WriteLine(Newlist) but the variable name is Test ?